# Bootstrap 4 big margin in parent container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Okay, this is my 3rd question and hopefully the last one. I get some problems with my page layout that looked like this before:

```
[navbar]                            
[1][2][3]
```

I wanted to achieve this effect when resizing:

```
[navbar]             
[2][3]         
   [1]
```

(1st div under the 3rd one)

However, when I use (in the main container that holds all the 3 divs) class `container mt-3` I get this layout:

```
[navbar]             
[1][2]                                                                          
   [3]
```

Now, when I change the margin-left of the 3rd div it doesn't go up to the top row but just moves to the left - something happens like it would be in another row class.

When I use parent-container `container mt-3`

```
[navbar]             
[1][2]   [3]
```

And they are really small and I can't change the width no matter what I do. I even tried changing the bootstrap's "container" class with both px and %.

container-fluid does the job a bit because all the divs are bigger (and on 100% width of the page) but I would want to have it just like 90%, but still, the [3] div is on the right side mile from the [2]. When I resize the window, the [2] div goes in this white space between [1] and [3] under the [3]. So it looks similar to this:

```
[navbar]                                       
[2]   [3]          
   [1]
```

CSS CODE:

```
.main{
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px #000000;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.left{
    background-color: green;
    max-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.right{
    background-color: blue;
    max-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;    
}   

.parent-container {
    display: flex;
}

.right-content{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent-container container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left col-4 col-lg-3 order-last order-lg-first offset-8 offset-lg-0">
            <div class="col-12 text-center" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                <h3>TITLE LEFT</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-8 col-lg-6">
            <div class="container card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <h2>TITLE CENTER</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                <h3>heading 3</h3>
                                <h6>heading 6</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
                        <a href="#" class="article-link">
                            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                            <p>Text</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="right col-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="right-content">
                <h2>TITLE RIGHT</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are using bootstpra V4 so remove all these margin and consider updating order and alignment

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had improper nesting for the columns. Here's the right way to do it (all main columns must sit within the main row):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.left{
    background-color: green;
    max-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.right{
    background-color: blue;
    max-width: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;    
} 
</style>

<div class="parent-container container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left col-4 col-lg-3 order-last order-lg-first offset-8 offset-lg-0">
            <h3>TITLE LEFT</h3>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-8 col-lg-6">
            <div class="container2 card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <h2>TITLE CENTER</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                            <h3>heading 3</h3>
                            <h6>heading 6</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
                    <a href="#" class="article-link">
                        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <div class="right col-4 col-lg-3">
            <div class="right-content">
                <h2>TITLE RIGHT</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Right now the columns aren't stacking on the smallest screens. That's because they aren't specified to do so. To make them stack, the responsive column classes for the smallest screens (`col-*`) all need to be changed to `col-12`.

You'd also need to adjust the offset classes because right now the `offset-8` class kicks in for all screens that are smaller than `lg`. The `offset-8` class is what causes the offset of 8 units (on the left) on all screens that are smaller than `lg`.

Comment: Problem that I have now, is that the main div ([2]) is higher than both left and right ([1] and [3]). The left div goes under the right (vertically) but horizontally it is under the main. When I changed the main div's height to 10px everything worked perfect. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Well, didn't you want the left div to be underneath the right div? I think the main problem is that you haven't actually specified what positioning you want on smaller screens. You've only ever specified what you want it to look like on larger screens. If you want the positions to be different on smaller screens, you need to specify exactly how they need to be positioned on smaller screens and also specify from which breakpoint do you expect it to switch from large screen view to small screen view.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear for you, but I wanted to change the left div's position to be under the right one when resizing the window to smaller one (e.g. medium). Your answers worked perfect but I want the left div to be just under the right - this works but when the main div (centre one) is smaller than the right div.

Comment: Your last comment doesn't make it any clearer to me. On the one hand, you keep saying "this works as needed" but on the other hand you are saying "it doesn't work." Please read my previous comment and specify exactly what needs to happen at what screen size. Don't say "it works" if it doesn't. Say exactly what doesn't work and at which screen size it doesn't work.

Comment: I have a full screen. I have left, main and right div in one row. When I resize the browser's window to a bootstrap's md size, the left div goes under the right but with a huge margin. Your solution doesn't work when my left div is 300px, my centre (main) is 700px and my right 300px. The left div goes to the right side but is at the bottom of the page, horizontally just under the centre div.. Including dimensions from above, my desired effect can only be achieved by adding "margin-top:-400px". Your solution works ONLY when the centre div's height is smaller than right div, in this case < 300px

Comment: I think you should try making pictures instead of explaining things with words because your explanations, once again, don't make any sense to me. For example, 300px + 700px + 300px adds up to 1300px etc. etc. Basically, the more I try to read your text the LESS clearer things become to me. And as of right now I have not the slightest clue what exactly should happen at what screen size. Try by drawing pictures AND make sure to each picture there's an annotation saying what screen size that's for.

Comment: When you create the pictures for an explanation, please post that stuff as a separate question because I really want to avoid unnecessary trouble with Stack Overflow moderators. Use the exact code I posted here as a basis for that new question and attach images that explain what exactly should happen at what screen size. That should eliminate any confusion.